# Dropdown delay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

So I'm working on a drop down menu and I'm having a problem.  If you hover on it in a certain way, the dropdown menu goes up and down non-stop.  Here is the JS:

```
$("#solar-slide").hover(function() {
    $("ul", this).slideDown(100);
},
function() {
    $("ul", this).slideUp(100);
    }
);
```

If you'd like to try it yourself, go to mjevange.mysite.syr.edu/SE

Thanks

Comment: seems fine to me, what browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding stop():

```
$("#solar-slide").hover(function() {
    $("ul", this).stop(true).slideDown(100);
},
function() {
    $("ul", this).stop(true).slideUp(100);
    }
);
```

Comment: I have recently done something like this on my site. Animations are stored and refreshed every time you reinstaniate via jQuery. You need to store the `$("ul" this)` in a variable and continually reference that otherwise it doesn't really work as intended.

Comment: how do i store that in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're moving the menu item on hover. Removing `top: 1px;` from your `.button:hover` css should fix it.